# Tidier way of getting Directory Names only from Blob Container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get the directory names only of any directories in a specific location withing Blob Storage

I have the helper class below

```
public static class BlobHelper
{
    private static CloudBlobContainer _cloudBlobContainer;
    private const string _containerName = "administrator";

    public static void Setup(string connectionString)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        _cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(_containerName);

    }


    public static List<string> GetDirectoryNames(string relativeAddress)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var directory = _cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(relativeAddress);
        var folders = directory.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>();

        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            var name = folder.Uri.AbsolutePath;
            name = name.Replace(folder.Parent.Prefix, string.Empty)
                .Replace(@"/", string.Empty)
                .Replace(_containerName, string.Empty);

            result.Add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

The process to get the directory names only (i.e. not the full hierarchy) feels a bit hacky, although it does work

Is there a better way to do this?

I tried the approach below

```
var directory = _cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(relativeAddress);        
var blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true).OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>();;
var blobNames = blobs.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
return blobNames;
```

The main difference with the above is the use of UseFlatBlobListing as true

However, this approach results in no folders at all being returned, whereas my other logic does at least give me the 2 folders I expect to find

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Why do you think your 1st solution is "hacky"?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your code is OK, I don't understand what you mean "a bit hacky". I think you want to get the directory directly.

Cause no method directory get the directory, for now known method to do it with v11 sdk mostly use the blob uri to do it.

And the below is my way to do it.

```
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

            BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;

            var blobsSeg = cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmented(null, blobContinuationToken);

            var directories= blobsSeg.Results.OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>().Select(b => b.Prefix).ToList();
            foreach (string directory in directories) {
                Console.WriteLine(directory);
            }
```

The result it returns it will be like below pic. Hope this could help you.

[image]